# I am getting current date while selecting Future date

Tags: android, datepicker

Here Is my code, I am selecting future but getting current date,
how to get date what I have selected ?

```java
Calendar mcurrentDate = Calendar.getInstance();

year = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
month = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
day = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

final DatePickerDialog mDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(WesternRecMoneyActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker datepicker, int selectedyear, int electedmonth, int selectedday) 
    {
        binding.recvPassExpDate.setText(new 
        StringBuilder().append(day).append("/").append(month + ).append("/").append(year));
        int month_k = selectedmonth + 1;
    }
}, year, month, day);

// Hide Past Date Here
mDatePicker.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
mDatePicker.show();
```

Answer (score 4):

> I am getting current date while selecting Future date

Because you are not setting the selected date from your `DatePicker`

Check your `onDateSet() method`

You need to use `selectedday`, `selectedmonth`, `selectedyear` of `onDateSet() method`

Use this

```
binding.recvPassExpDate.setText(new 
                              StringBuilder().append(selectedday).append("/").append(selectedmonth 
                                     + 1).append("/").append(selectedyear));
```

Instead of this

```
binding.recvPassExpDate.setText(new 
                                 StringBuilder().append(day).append("/").append(month 
                                     + 1).append("/").append(year));
```

Comment: @PoojaPatwa Glad to have been of help! Feel free to [accept my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) if you feel it was useful to you. :-)